# How can I prevent from script from dying if a process ID doesn't exist?

Tags: bash, shell-script, process, su

I'm using bash shell on Ubuntu Linux 14.04.  I have this script ...

```
SIDEKIQ_PID="$APP_ROOT/tmp/sidekiq.pid"
SIDEKIQ_STOP_CMD="cd $APP_ROOT && bundle exec sidekiqctl stop $SIDEKIQ_PID 0"
...
    su - $USER -c "$SIDEKIQ_STOP_CMD"
    echo "Stopped sidekiq"
```

What I'm noticing is that if the PID no longer exists that is defined in my file "$SIDEKIQ_PID", the line

```
su - $USER -c "$SIDEKIQ_STOP_CMD"
```

dies with a "Process doesn't exist" error and the script doesn't continue (I can't see the following echo statement).  How can I make my script continue even if the process no longer exists?

Comment: Should the `stop` subcommand take a PID _file_ or a PID (number)?

Comment: Everything works fine when the PID in taht file exists so I assume its good the way I have it, at least in regards to what comes after "stop".

Comment: First test whether the PID still exists with `kill -0 $PID` (this needs to be executed by the owner of the process or root).  If the exit code is zero, the PID exists, and proceed; elsewise, handle the case of "this PID no longer exists".

Comment: YOu have basically restated my question.  WHen the PID doesn't exist, the line "su - $USER -c "$SIDEKIQ_STOP_CMD"" is dyihng and the script isn't executed after that.  I would like the script to continue.

Comment: Given what you have shown, there is no reason the script should selfterminate after `kill` throws an error for an invalie PID.

Comment: Is errexit set for the shell invocation?

Comment: I haven't explicitly set errexit no.

Comment: maybe it's been inherited? I'd add `echo $SHELLOPTS | grep errexit` just above the `su` to see.

Comment: any confirmation of the "errexit" shell option being set or unset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to get around the errexit setting without turning it off is to make the command return success.

Example:

```
set -e
false  # script exits here
```

vs.

```
set -e
false || true   # script no longer exits
```

So maybe try

```
su - $USER -c "$SIDEKIQ_STOP_CMD" || true
```